# Is there any truth in this warning since I use a Using block?

Tags: vb.net, dispose, using, skiasharp

I have just run Visual Studio's own code analysis with the "All Microsoft rules" setting. This warning came up:

> "CA2000: Call System.IDisposable.Dispose in the "FormMain.processing()" method for the "New SKPaint()" object before all references to it are outside the valid scope."

But: I'm using a `using block`. There is no need to write `.Dispose()`, right? What's happening?

I have to mention that the automatic garbage collection clears the memory after about 26–30 seconds. I can see that in the diagnostic tools. The memory consumption increases by then up to approximately 800 MB. However, I never saw in the SkiaSharp documentation that you have to write `.Dispose` yourself.

**This is my original code. For a minimally reproducible example, see below.**

```
#Disable Warning CA2007 ' Aufruf von "ConfigureAwait" für erwarteten Task erwägen
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private ReadOnly List_of_ComplexNumbers_in_the_timespan As New List(Of ComplexNumber)
    Private Shared displayedBitmap As Drawing.Bitmap
    Private Shared ReadOnly Rand As New Random
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer_GC.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStop.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
        Timer_GC.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Await Task.Run(Sub() processing())
    End Sub

    Private Sub processing()
        List_of_ComplexNumbers_in_the_timespan.Clear()

        'Test filling
        List_of_ComplexNumbers_in_the_timespan.Add(New ComplexNumber(Rand.Next(-5, 5),
                                                                     Rand.Next(-5, 5)))
        List_of_ComplexNumbers_in_the_timespan.Add(New ComplexNumber(Rand.Next(-5, 5),
                                                                     Rand.Next(-5, 5)))

        displayedBitmap = Nothing

        Using surface As SkiaSharp.SKSurface = SkiaSharp.SKSurface.Create(New SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo(PictureBox1.Size.Width,
                                                                                                    PictureBox1.Size.Height))
            Using canvas As SkiaSharp.SKCanvas = surface.Canvas
                canvas.Translate(PictureBox1.Size.Width \ 2,
                                 PictureBox1.Size.Height \ 2)
                Using Magenta As New SkiaSharp.SKPaint With {
                            .IsAntialias = True,
                            .Color = New SkiaSharp.SKColor(255, 0, 64),
                            .Style = SkiaSharp.SKPaintStyle.Fill
                            }

                    'point of origin
                    canvas.DrawLine(-50.0F, 0.0F, 50.0F, 0.0F, Magenta)
                    canvas.DrawLine(0.0F, -50.0F, 0.0F, 50.0F, Magenta)

                    For Each Instance As ComplexNumber In List_of_ComplexNumbers_in_the_timespan
                        Dim SKPoints0 As New SkiaSharp.SKPoint(Instance.x * 50.0F + 2.0F, -(Instance.y * 50.0F + 2.0F))
                        Dim SKPoints1 As New SkiaSharp.SKPoint(Instance.x * 50.0F - 2.0F, -(Instance.y * 50.0F - 2.0F))
                        Dim SKPoints2 As New SkiaSharp.SKPoint(Instance.x * 50.0F, -(Instance.y * 50.0F))
                        canvas.DrawPoints(SkiaSharp.SKPointMode.Lines,
                                          {SKPoints0, SKPoints1, SKPoints2},
                                          Magenta)
                    Next

                End Using
            End Using

            '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
            ' Get the data into displayedBitmap because the PictureBox is only accepting an usual System.Drawing.Bitmap.
            '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

            Using image As SkiaSharp.SKImage = surface.Snapshot()
                Using data As SkiaSharp.SKData = image.Encode(SkiaSharp.SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100)
                    Using mStream As New IO.MemoryStream(data.ToArray())
                        displayedBitmap = New Drawing.Bitmap(mStream, False)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        PictureBox1.Image = displayedBitmap
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_GC_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_GC.Tick
        GC.Collect()
    End Sub
End Class
#Enable Warning CA2007 ' Aufruf von "ConfigureAwait" für erwarteten Task erwägen
```

```
Public NotInheritable Class ComplexNumber
    Public Property x As Single
    Public Property y As Single
    Public Sub New(ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
        Me.x = x
        Me.y = y
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**minimal reproducible example** You need 2 Buttons, 1 Timer, and 1 PictureBox. You also need to install SkiaSharp.
[image: how to install SkiaSharp in the NuGet Package Manager]

```
Public NotInheritable Class Form1
    Private Shared displayedBitmap As Drawing.Bitmap
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        displayedBitmap = Nothing

        Using surface As SkiaSharp.SKSurface = SkiaSharp.SKSurface.Create(New SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo(PictureBox1.Size.Width,
                                                                                                    PictureBox1.Size.Height))
            Using canvas As SkiaSharp.SKCanvas = surface.Canvas
                canvas.Translate(PictureBox1.Size.Width \ 2,
                                 PictureBox1.Size.Height \ 2)
                Using Magenta As New SkiaSharp.SKPaint With {
                            .IsAntialias = True,
                            .Color = New SkiaSharp.SKColor(255, 0, 64),
                            .Style = SkiaSharp.SKPaintStyle.Fill
                            }

                    'point of origin
                    canvas.DrawLine(-50.0F, 0.0F, 50.0F, 0.0F, Magenta)
                    canvas.DrawLine(0.0F, -50.0F, 0.0F, 50.0F, Magenta)
                End Using
            End Using

            '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
            ' Get the data into displayedBitmap because the PictureBox is only accepting an usual System.Drawing.Bitmap.
            '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

            Using image As SkiaSharp.SKImage = surface.Snapshot()
                Using data As SkiaSharp.SKData = image.Encode(SkiaSharp.SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100)
                    Using mStream As New IO.MemoryStream(data.ToArray())
                        displayedBitmap = New Drawing.Bitmap(mStream, False)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        PictureBox1.Image = displayedBitmap
    End Sub
End Class
```

The same warning appears.

[image: Warning]

Comment: Strange indeed, your code looks fine. Can you try to create a [mcve], so that others can try to reproduce the issue with their version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @Heinzi I've edit the question. I've added a minimal example.

Comment: `New SkiaSharp.SKPaint With...` does it still happen if you don't use `With`? That is, split up the `Using` and the property assignment into separate statements. I have little experience with VB.NET here, but I know precisely this issue is present in C# if using the `using (var x = new Object { Prop = value, ... }` syntax, since, for whatever reason, the compiler implements this as a `new` followed by the assignments and only *then* starting the `using` block, which leaves a gap where the instance could end up undisposed. [See also](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2930).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you. This did help.  ```Using Magenta As New SkiaSharp.SKPaint
                    Magenta.IsAntialias = True
                    Magenta.Color = New SkiaSharp.SKColor(255, 0, 64)
                    Magenta.Style = SkiaSharp.SKPaintStyle.Fill```

Comment: Drawing.Bitmap has a Dispose method which needs to be called.